# Oracle SQL - trying to calculate running total with Group By without having an existing numerical column to sum

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, window-functions

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I've got the following table structure, and I'm trying to get a running total of the count of products, grouped by date and product, i.e. for each distinct date in Date_Ordered, I want each distinct Product listed, and the sum of how many times it's appeared up to, and including, that date.

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| Reference | Product    | Date_Orderd | ... |
+===========+============+=============+=====+
| x-123123  | Product 1  | 02/02/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123124  | Product 2  | 02/02/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123125  | Product 3  | 02/02/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| ...       | ...        | ...         | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123241  | Product 2  | 24/03/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123242  | Product 1  | 25/03/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| ...       | ...        | ...         | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123620  | Product 10 | 02/05/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
| x-123621  | Product 7  | 02/05/2020  | ... |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----+
```

The problem I'm having is that all the examples I've found for this (e.g. https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/ , https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1793764100346222947 , https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-to-calculate-a-running-total-with-sql-986d0019185c) seem to assume that there's a column in the table with a numerical value to be summed.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get the data I need?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: It would be good to show based on your example, how the end data would look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a given product is never ordered twice on the same data, you can just use a window count:

```
select
    t.*,
    count(*) over(partition by reference order by date_ordered) running_count
from mytable t
```

If there are duplicates, then you need aggregation:

```
select  
    reference,
    date_ordered,
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by reference order by date_ordered) running_count
from mytable
group by reference, date_ordered
```

Finally: if you want to generate all combinations of dates and product, with the associated runnig count, then you would do:

```
select
    r.reference,
    d.date_ordered,
    sum(count(t.reference)) over(partition by r.reference order by d.date_ordered) running_count
from (select distinct date_ordered from mytable) d
cross join (select distinct reference from mytable) r
left join mytable t 
    on t.date_ordered = d.date_ordered and t.reference = r.reference
group by d.date_ordered, r.reference
```